# TinyMCE editor is not getting the mouse or cursor focus / is not editable in Firefox 14.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, tinymce

In my Rails App, I have two forms one inside another and in each of which I have two text areas which should be used along with the editor. I have integrated the TinyMCE edtor perfectly and it is embedded with the text area on page load. But I could only edit the first text area and I can't get my mouse point or the cursor point inside the second text area/ not editable at all in Firefox 14.0.1. This feature is working perfectly with Chrome and IE. The text areas i have used has the following DOM structure.

```
<textarea style="width: 426px; height: 117px; border: 1px solid rgb(209, 209, 209); float: left; display: none;" name="description" id="question-text" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input description" aria-hidden="true">&lt;p&gt;bfdfghdfghd&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>


<textarea style="width: 426px; height: 117px; border: 1px solid rgb(209, 209, 209); float: left; display: none;" name="description" id="sub_question-text" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input sub_description" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
```

I dont know why the second one is not editable. Please help.

Comment: Hey any TinyMCE masters here? I need to resolve the above.